# removing '|' from a list from the end of a string in python

Tags: python

I want to write a code which will remove the '|' from a string if that pipe is in the last.

Input data sample :

```
ABC|CDE|FGH|XYZ
ABC|CDE|FGH|
ABC|
CDN
```

The code which I have written is :

```
with open(OUT_FILE, 'a') as outputfile:
    with open(INTER_FILE, 'rb') as feed:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        reader = csv.reader(feed, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:   
            reportable_jurisdiction=row[7]
        if '|' in reportable_jurisdiction:
            print 'length ',len(list(row[7].split('|')))
            print ' List : ', list(row[7].split('|'))
            if len(filter(None,list(row[7].split('|')))) == 1:
                row[7]=filter(None,list(row[7].split('|')))
                print " row ", row[7]
                row[7]="".join(sorted(list(row[7].split('|'))))
            else:
                row[7]="|".join(sorted(list(row[7].split('|'))))
                print " reportable Jurisdiction with comma "+reportable_jurisdiction
        else:
            print "reportable Jurisdiction if single "+reportable_jurisdiction

        writer.writerow(row)
    feed.close()
    outputfileSize=os.path.getsize(OUT_FILE)
    outputfile.close()
```

Here I am sorting the data and again preparing the String with pipe separated. 
Now the problem here is the String which do not have "|" in the last like ABC|CDE|FGH|XYZ and ABC are fine and those are comming as ABC|CDE|FGH|XYZ but the Strings which is having "|" in the last like "ABC|CDE|EFG|" those are coming as |ABC|CDE|FGH and "ABC|" is coming as "|ABC".

But the expected output is:

|ABC|CDE|FGH|XYZ
ABC|CDE|FGH
ABC
CDN

Thanks in advance for the guidence.

Comment: try to write code, at least try ... Then, post it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rstrip`

```
x = 'ABC|DEF|'
x.rstrip('|')

'ABC|DEF'
```